# jQuery Datatables Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am using Angularjs as the frontend and spring mvc as the backened for my application. I am using datatables for displaying records. The problem I am facing is datatables works sometimes and sometimes doesn't.

After performing edit or delete or any dynamic operations the datatable loses its shape like pagination, filtration, search. Even though there will be data but it shows there are no records but still it displays records with no pagination.

I tried `draw()` and `reload` methods in the script but nothing seemed to work.
In html pages my order of loading css and js files are like this

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="adminApp">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/front/css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/front/css/Custom-Style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/front/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/front/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/front/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" ref="resources/front/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/angular/angulars-datetime-picker.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/front/css/spinner.css">
      <script src="resources/front/js/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="resources/front/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/front/js/Custom-js.js"></script>
      <script src="resources/front/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/front/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/front/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This is the script where I tried everything. I have placed this inside the `head` tag. I have placed all the above code in every html file.

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

Here is how i am using ng-repeat for displaying data in table

```
    <div class="TableBox">
    <table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" 
    cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example"
    rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="" >
    SlNo
    </th>
    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example"
    rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" 
    aria-label="">Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="even" data-ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{student.studentName}}
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my AngularController.js

```
    $scope.getAllStudents = function()
    {
        AdminStudentService.getAllStudents().then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.students=response.data;
    });
    }
```

Here is my update method

```
    $scope.updateStudent = function(student)
    {
    $scope.editstudentForm.$submitted= true;
    if($scope.editstudentForm.$valid)
    {
    AdminStudentService.updateStudent(student).then(function(response)
    {
        if(response.data=="success")
        {
            $scope.editstudentForm.$submitted= false;
            $window.scrollTo(0,0);
            $scope.student = {};
            $scope.getAllStudents();
            $scope.successmessage1="Student Details Updated!;
            $timeout(function() 
            {
                $scope.closeeditStudent();
                $scope.successmessage1="";
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Am I missing something in the script or do I need to add something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing you with .js function that will help you understand datatables.

```
$scope.getAllReports = function() {
  $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : '/getReport'
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.test = data;
    $('#stack').DataTable().clear().draw();
    angular.forEach($scope.test, function(test) {
      $('#mantisi').DataTable().row.add([                           
        test.t0,
        test.t1,
        test.t2,
        test.t3,
        test.t4,
        test.t5
      ]).draw();
    });
  });
};
```

Also here is code from .html:

```
<table id="stack" class="table table-bordered table-striped" ng-init="getAllReports()">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>t0</th>
      <th>t1</th>
      <th>t2</th>
      <th>t3</th>
      <th>t4</th>
      <th>t5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And also a .js for DT:

```
$('#stack').DataTable({
  "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  "language": {
    url: '/datatables/datatables.hr.json'
  },
  "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
    $(".btn-excel-custom").removeClass("dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5");
    $(".btn-default-custom").removeClass("dt-button").addClass("btn btn-default");
  },
  "bPaginate": false,
  dom: 'Bfrt',    
  buttons: [{
    text:"Export to Excel",
    extend: 'excel',
    className: 'btn btn-excel-custom'
  }]
});
```

These are 3 main snippets for decent show-up of jQuery datatables. Also, I've created special methods provided by DT API in last snippet.

Comment: I have updated my question.Can you suggest me an edit in the same if anything is possible.I have added <table> tag in which i am using ng-repeat to loop through the records that i am getting as response from backened.And also i have added Controller.js function.

Comment: are you calling a method that will reinitialize datatable with newest data after changing some fields? So basicly, you have to call again ng-init method to repopulate datatable with fresh data.

Comment: I am not calling method.I am just placing the script as i have mentioned above.Where do i need to call init method? Because after doing update of any fields i am calling getAllStudents() method in AngularController.js.As soon as it gets updated it will display newly updated fields.But pagination and filtration properties disappears

Comment: I have added the update method also in the question that i am using to update Student details.